# Background-image не работает

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Свойство background-image не работает в файле css. 
Файл находится в папке css.
**css/style.css**

```
body {
 background-image: url(img/a.png);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Но в самом файле html свойство background-image работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-image: url(img/a.png);
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите, почему не работает, если я размещаю в в файле css?

Comment: Вы не правильно путь прописываете!

Answer (score 5):

в css файле пропишите

```
body {
   background-image: url(../img/a.png); /* выходим из папки css на уровень вверх, и заходим в папку img */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает. Вот почему в index.html работает без перехода на один уровень вверх ( ../ ), не пойму...

Comment: @Anton121212, потому что index.html находится на одном уровне с папкой img. И поэтому в index.html путь будет выглядеть прямым img/a.png

Comment: Спасибо! Я все понял!

Comment: Но не стоит забывать,что находясь на сервере точки не нужны и перед img нужно ставит "/"

Answer (score 1):

Между тегами `<head>` у вас некорректно написана ссылка на файл CSS.
Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>New Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Как видите вы не дописали `type="text/css"` в теге `link`.

Comment: В HTML5 считается корректно. В HTML4, разумеется нет.

Comment: Да и я не заметил, что у ТС css находится в другой папке. Тоже моя ошибка. :)

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой.
Решил!
Изображения формата .png почему-то не отображаются этим свойством, а вот .jpg и .webp отображаются

Answer (score 0):

```
  body {
   background-image: url(../img/a.png);
  }
```

http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает. Вот почему в index.html работает без перехода на один уровень вверх ( ../ ), не пойму...

Answer (score 0):

пол суток пробовал

```
background-image: url(../img/a.png);

background-image: url("../img/a.png");
```

,а оказывается надо вот так

```
background-image: url('../img/a.png');
```

все заработало ;)

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет. Была такая же проблема: не работал backgrounf-image: url(link). Мучался часа 2, перепробовал всё, любые модификации но проблема оставалась. Ошибка заключалась в том, что не правильно был указан путь к картинке (файлу), и как не старался - ничего не помогало. Потом, когда я начал думать что html и css - не моё, мне вдруг пришла в голову мысль залезть в настройки. Я пользуюсь Notepad++ и обнаружил вот что: в пункте "Путь по умолчанию" было отмечено "запомнить последнюю директорию", я переставил отметку на "пройти за текущим документом", а в значении селектора background-image указал папку и файл: background-image: url(images/1.jpg)
И все заработало.
Надеюсь, кому да поможет инфа.

Answer (score -1):

Судя по имени стиля вам нужен фон страницы. 
Если не работает, то проверьте правильный ли путь к картинке. то есть ../img/a.png или /img/a.png

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        background: url("img/a.png") repeat scroll left top #FFFFFF;
        overflow-y: scroll;

    }
```

Comment: Если не работает, то проверьте правильный ли путь к картинке. то есть ../img/a.png или /img/a.png

Answer (score -1):

Может помочь указания размеров картинки фона.

```
.image {
    background-image: url(img/a.png);
    width: 50px; /* ширина */
    height: 50px; /* высота */
}
```