# Не получается изменить картинку(кнопку) при наведении на нее курсора в position: fixed

Tags: css, css3, html5, css-animation

Не получается изменить картинку при наведении на нее курсора. Есть две картинки-кнопки.png надо, чтобы одна заменила другую при наведении на неё мыши.[image: Исходное изображение]

[image: Изображение кнопки заменяемое при клике]
Важный момент кнопка находится в
position: fixed;

[Пытался решить проблему с помощью этого сайта](https://webcodius.ru/spravochnik-css/kak-izmenit-kartinku-pri-navedenii-na-nee-kursora.html)
Пробовал объединять картинки с использованием объединённого изображения [image: Объединённое изображение]

```css
.knopka {
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 130px;
}

img.knopka {
    display: block;
    /* Ширина рисунка в пикселах */
    width: 48px;
    /* Высота рисунка в пикселах */
    height: 48px;
}

img.knopka:hover {
    background-position: 0 48px;
    /* Смещение фона */
}
```

```html
<div class="knopka">
            <a href="#top"> <img src="Images/upItog.png" width="48"> </a>
        </div>
```

По итогу этого способа изначально на странице видны сразу 2 изображения, вместо одного. При наведении - ничего не меняется.

Пробовал исходную картинку сделать фоном элемента div с помощью свойства background. А при наведении на картинку курсора менять фоновую картинку с помощью псевдокласса hover(здесь я использовал два изображения):

```css
.knopka {
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 130px;
}

div.knopka {
    background: url(Images/up.png);
    /* Путь к файлу с исходным рисунком */
    width: 48px;
    /* Ширина рисунка */
}

div.knopka:hover {
    background: url(Images/upAct.png);
    /* Путь к файлу с заменяемым рисунком */
}
```

```html
<div class="knopka">
            <a href="#top"> </a>
</div>
```

В ходе выполнения кнопка вообще исчезла.
Пробовал подкладывать одну картинку под другую с использованием `opacity:0;` или `opacity:1;` картинки перестали быть видны на сайте. Заранее спасибо за ответ.
**Включил режим отладки в Хроме и по итогу он выделяет блок в нужном мне месте, но там нет никакой картинки - блок пуст: [image: Расположение блока без кнопки]**
Кстати, в самом файле html свойство background-image работает. Может проблема в некорректном url. html файл находится отдельно - в папке с другими папками, а уже внутри общей папки находится CSS-папка с CSS, JS-папка с JS и Imades-папка с картинками.
**Да, 5-часовая проблема из-за некорректного url) [Я нашёл ответ по этому адресу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299376/background-image-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82) Спасибо humster_spb за терпение и "вникаемость" в чужие проблемы**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вариант у Вас вполне рабочий, просто Вы забыли высоту задать, а без неё фоновой картинки не видно (содержимого-то в блоке нет).

```css
.knopka {
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 130px;
}

div.knopka {
    background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/163385/pub_5b144e7155876b04b08e1f9d_5b14657e5a104ffc196531df/scale_1200');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}

div.knopka:hover {
    background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/164147/pub_5ce7ed349676d700b3066fb7_5ce7ee75cb1ea900b242b36a/scale_1200');
    /* Путь к файлу с заменяемым рисунком */
}
```

```html
<div class="knopka">
            <a href="#top"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @humster_spb я выполнил код в вашем сообщении и он работает. Но я дополнил свой код и он не работает

Comment: @DmitryDak, обратите внимание - помимо высоты я добавил в css background-size: cover и написал background-image (а не просто background), чтобы корректно работало. Возможно, Ваша проблема в этом.

Comment: Не, я их тоже изменил, согласно вашему коду - не работает

Comment: @DmitryDak, а что именно не работает?

Comment: Нет кнопки(картинки) и на неё нельзя кликнуть. Кнопка выполняет функцию "наверх" Можно подумать, что я неправильно подключил файл CSS, но остальные стили и файл JS на странице работают.