# background-image не ставит картинку

Tags: css, background-image

Уже все проверял, но картинки нету. :с

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="logo">text stack</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
.logo {
    background-image: url(../image/logo.png)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Посмотрите в DevTools (консоли разработчика) браузере, находит ли он путь до картинки

Comment: Да, там все гуд

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Background-image не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299376/background-image-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: Путь указан верно
+ добавил в link - type="text/css"
И ничего

Comment: Вряд ли это что-то изменит, но добавьте `type="text/css"` к тегу `link`

Comment: Выше отписал, что добавил) - но увы

Comment: 1. Поставьте `;` псоле `background-image: url(../image/logo.png)`. 2. Очистите кэш `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`. Больше у меня вариантов нету, все выглядит нормально. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Аж самому стало интересно

Comment: Не получается) Но я попробовал "* {
    background-image: url(../image/logo.png);
}" - тут все работает. А на теги и классы - нет...

Comment: высоту добавьте в класс. пикселей 1000

Comment: Добавил height - появилось. Спасибо. Я не знаю как тут отметить "решено"

Comment: В комментариях никак. Если ответить, рядом галочка появляется.

Comment: @eccs0103: _"Аж самому стало интересно"_ Ничего интересного, всё по классике - нам в вопросе дают один код, а ответы применяют совсем к другому :)

Comment: @UModeL этот просто среди классики интересно)

Comment: @eccs0103: 100%, что текст в блоке только в примере, а в реальном коде там пусто. Потому блок нулевой высоты, вместе со своим фоном :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У картинки нет размера, поэтому размер у нее 0. Поставьте в абсолютных или в процентах ширину и высоту в css:

```
.logo {
    background-image: url(image/logo.png);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: У вас `url` с пути сбился